# Code coverage with jacoco for a Android library

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, code-coverage, jacoco

I have an Android library (jar file) containing some APIs and I want to do code coverage test for these APIs using Jacoco.

For example, I have a calculator library (may name it calc.jar), having some APIs to do add, subtract, multiple and divide (via some static method such as Calc.doAdd(a,b), Calc.doSubtract(a,b) etc...). Now I have another Android test application (created by Android Studio) using this calculator library. I would like to do code coverage for this calculator library (surely I have calculator library source code).

I am also successfully do code coverage test with EMMA and ant. 
As  Android Studio now uses Gradle for building, so I would like to know if we can do code coverage (I searched and see that Gradle can work with Jacoco).

I do searched and see that there are some topic relating to Jacoco code coverage for Android Application. But I am looking a way for doing code coverage for JAR library using Jacoco and Gradle. Please give me a help.
If there are topics relating to this, please help to show me.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Issue 76373](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76373) you can't get code coverage for libraries. Some people seems to have been successful with some hacks but I've not found anything that works for me.